Benefits of using language as global option?
In the following document, I have the choice between passing danish as a global option or just as an option to babel. What difference will this make in practice? Are there any benefits to using the option globally as opposed to locally for babel? Are there any packages that rely on this instead of just obtaining the document language from babel?
Why am I interested in this? I am using a document template for writing job applications. I write the actual content in external files, using e.g. \newcommand\applicationtext{...}. I would also like to set the language and other options in these external files or add other code specifically for this particular application. If I have to \input this external file before \documentclass, that means that I cannot easily load packages from it without using workaround solutions. And that makes the system all the more cumbersome and inflexible.
\documentclass[danish]{article}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{babel}
%\usepackage[danish]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes,biblatex}

\begin{document}

Hej Verden

\end{document}


"Are there any packages that rely on this instead of just obtaining the document language from babel" Given the number of available packages, you will always find one which does not take the language from babel. For example the translator package.

`\documentclass[danish]{article}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}
%\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{translator}
\usedictionary{translator-basic-dictionary}
\begin{document}
\translate{authors}
\end{document}
`

Also consider the third case in which babel needs to be used with \babelprovide to explicitly set up a language (I think there are some RTL languages which need this special treatment)

Babel also includes hyphenation data, which differs from language to language.

Actually, babel doesn’t “set” the language. The language is set as a class (or package) option and then babel defines or redefines locale dependent captions, date, line breaking, etc., based on this setting. This is the standard way to deal with languages in latex, and babel has no special status.
Apart from babel, there are at least 15 packages understanding the danish option, among others varioref, translator, pdfscreen, isodate, gloss, datetime...
\babelprovide is somewhat anomalous, but now there is an alternative following the standard syntax, with the package option provide= (see the latest versions of the manual). For example:
\documentclass[chinese]{article}
\usepackage[provide={ intraspace=0 .2 0, mapdigits }]{babel}

is similar to:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main, intraspace=0 .2 0, mapdigits ]{chinese}

but with the former any package knows the language is chinese.
A question:

If I have to \input this external file before \documentclass.

Why do you need that?

Well, because if I want to set the language in that external file, I need it before \documentclass, right? What I do is to define a command \documentlanguageoptions and do \expandafter\documentclass\expandafter[\documentlanguageoptions]{memoir}. Is there a way to set global options after \documentclass?

Please, could you be more explanatory? Why do you need to load a file before \documentclass. As @Teepeemm said, this is rarely necessary, and not usually a good idea.

I have a main file that I use for job application cover letters. Then I have a number of files, e.g. /place/<company name>/<company name>_application_1. In this file, I set the language of the application as well as the body text by defining commands, e.g. \newcommand\documentlanguage{danish} and \newcommand\applicationtext{...}. This makes it easier to globally control and manage the application layout of the template. It also allows me to go back and find old applications and re-submit them with any layout changes that I might have made since then.

I write some applications in Danish and others in English. Usually, I use the same language as in the job announcement. That is why I need to be able to control the language from the external file. And if I want to use this language as a global option, I have to define \documentlanguage before \documentclass.

@Gaussler: A much more standard way of handling that would be to put the shared structural code into a *.sty style file or *.cls class file of your own (which can be written to load an existing class and then extend/customise it), and then have each individual document begin by loading that shared class/style file.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine In order to be able to load that class from many different locations, I would need it to be in my TeX Live folder. But I like to back up my files by putting them in the Google Drive folder. There might be a way to make a class file in there globally available, but from what I read, it’s not really worth the hassle. My external file template system works fine most of the time, even if I need to apply some workaround solutions sometimes.

@Gaussler: Since your current setup already involves individual document files and a shared “main file” that they each import, then whatever file location(s) you currently use for the main file should work just fine with it changed to a class file.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Yeah, but then I’m going to have to do something like \documentclass{../../myclass}, which is ugly. And discouraged. And throws a warning. But I might consider it in the future.
